# 英語が残っている：基本設定の一番下「Personalized prediction settings」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

users/id/ユーザー名 -> 基本設定　の一番下に英語が残っていました。

[image: ユーザー情報の所]

ここの、基本設定をクリックし、一番下。

[image: Personalized prediction settings]

Comment: ひとまず[Transifexで特定](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289597?comment=%2Fq%2F1792%2F8000)しました。見出しの `Personalized prediction settings` は見つからず。

Comment: 現在開発者と確認中です。しばらくお待ちください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ユーザーの興味によってより適切なコンテンツを提供するプログラムです。

下記のコンテンツをターゲットさせています：

1. 広告（当サイトにありません）
2. モバイルの質問（モバイルアプリの日本語版がありません）

そのために、このプログラムは当コミュニティと関係はありません。

ご存知の通り、ユーザーが自分の興味を毎日示しています。例えば、ユーザープロフィルを見ると下記のようなことがあります：

[image: yohjpさんのプロフィル]

質問・回答により、どのタグに興味あるかが示しています。「Personalized Prediction Settings」は同じように当サイトでユーザーのアクティビティで興味を推奨することです。

[image: Stack Overflow Careersの広告]

英語版のSOでは、Stack Overflow Careersの広告があるため、もしそのターゲティングを使ってほしくない場合にopt-outはできますが、当サイトに広告がないため、翻訳を今の段階にしないつもりです。

Comment: サンプルに使われて笑ってしまった（別に嫌とかダメではないですが）

Answer (score 1):

いつからか設定画面が新しくなり、`users/preferences/<id>` に当該の設定が移りました。現在はこの部分もきちんと翻訳されています。